# I am really confused with understanding array pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *str = "Hello"; //defining and initializing the str pointer, which is directing to 'H'.

    printf("%s\n", str);
    printf("%p\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

The Result is:

```
Hello
0000000000404000
```

My question is where did 0000000000404000 come from?

Comment: no newline in the output? You should do `printf(%p\n", (void*)str);` instead, `%p` expects a `void` pointer.

Comment: That's just where the string happened to end up in the address space. It's completely arbitrary and not something you should rely on.

Comment: You have two `printf`s. What did you expect the second `printf` to do?

Comment: Please explain in the question what output you expected instead

Comment: It happens to be the address where `"Hello"` is stored in memory. It must be stored *somewhere* – so why not there?

Comment: So you mean that the second printf is printing the address of the pointer str, which is 'H'? @user2357112

Comment: So you mean that the second printf is printing the address of the pointer str, which is 'H'? @RadLexus

Comment: Yes, that's what it's doing. The `%p` format specification is for printing the value of a pointer, not what the pointer points to.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I finally understood what it is!! @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format specifier `%p` will print the address contained within the `char* str` variable whereas the `%s` specifier will print the actual string literal `Hello`.  The address in memory `0x00000000 00404000` is where `Hello` resides.

Comment: Thank you!! I finally understood what it is.

Comment: @ChrisLee if you understand from an answer you should accept it and vote for it

Answer (score 0):

In Bjarne Stroustrup words:

> `%s` The argument is taken to be a string (character pointer), and characters from the string
>   are printed until a null character or until the number of characters indicated by the precision specification is reached; however, if the precision is 0 or missing, all characters up to a null are printed;
>
> `%p` The argument is taken to be a pointer. The representation printed is implementation dependent;